# Blog Posts list Connect to Outlook disabled

Tags: list, blog, outlook, synchronisation, sync

I´m on SharePoint 2010, IE10

"Connect to Outlook" Button is disabled on blog post list. I noticed, that in some type of Lists this option is disabled even if site feature "Offline Synchronization for External Lists" is activated.

I know of workarounds like set up an alert or RRS Feed. Is there a reason why this option is disabled by default?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It is related to "Minimal Download Strategy":

> The reason why the "Connect to Outlook" is greyed out, is because
>   there is a feature called "Minimal Download Strategy". The feature
>   redirect you to an application page start.aspx, do some validation,
>   and loads start.js script. This add the "_layouts/15/start.aspx" in
>   the URL wich seems to break the Connect To Outlook functionnality.
>
> To go arround this, you have 2 choice;
>
> 1-Open you Calendar, Click the Calendar button in the top navigation
>   bar, and go to "List Settings". (4 buttons right from the connecto to
>   outlook)
>
> From there, copy the "Web Adress", and paste it in the adress bar of
>   your browser.
>
> Then go to the Connect to Outlook, it shouldn't be greyed out anymore.
>   It work for me on IE9 32bit with outlook 32 bits.
>
> 2- Go to the site settings of your collection, then to Manage Site
>   Features, and deactivate the Minimal Download Strategy" feature.
>
> The Minimal Download Strategy is actually a very good feature that you
>   migh want to keep though as it makes most of the apps load faster.
>
> I still don't know why this breaks it, but I'll do more research on
>   it.
>
> Let me know if this works for you as well.

Reference

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0ece1634-002b-4371-96ba-3a6c697d3694/connect-to-outlook-disabled?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Hi sorry I forgot to write, that I´m on SP2010. 1 Option: Does not work for me. 2 Option does not fit to SP2010 .......I´m talking about the posts lists on a SP Blog, where you can manage blog posts.